# Timout while connecting to Azure VM via Python

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, rdp

I am trying to connect Azure VM which is created via Administrator Password (Not SSH) but  have allowed SSH, HTTPS, and HTTP in Networking. But It's giving Timeout Error.

Tried to connect via paramiko library. Below is my code

```
import paramiko

results = []

def ssh_conn():
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect('IP_ADDRESS', port = 22, username='RDP_NAME', password='PASSWORD', timeout = 10)

        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = client.exec_command('ss -ltn')
        for line in ssh_stdout:
            results.apend(line.strip('\n'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

ssh_conn()

for i in results:
    print(i.strip())
```

What could be the reason for timeout?
Any new Way is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this in my local environment, we are able to execute and ssh into the VM using your shared python code using Visual studio code.

While testing your code we found that there is an false attribute `apend`  in the code so use  `append` instead of that attribute.
Because of this, code execution got failed and unable to connect to VM.

You can use the below code to connect to the VM:

> ````py
> import  paramiko
>
> results = []
>
> def  ssh_conn(): try: client = paramiko.SSHClient()
> client.load_system_host_keys()
> client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
> client.connect("4.****", port = 22, username="your username",
> password="your password")
>
> ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = client.exec_command("ss -ltn") for
> line  in  ssh_stdout: results.append(line.strip('\n')) except 
> Exception  as  e: print(e) ssh_conn()
>
> for  i  in  results: print(i.strip()) ```
> ````

***Output screen after connected to VM from python code is shown in the below screenshot:***

[image]

**Note:** SSH connectivity might getting timed out because of any firewall blocker.

Comment: I know that code is perfectly fine But the problem was timeout. I turned off the firewall but then it give an error of "NoValidConnectionsError" right away. I believe its Azure Firewall Rule. or should i create New Azure VM Machine with different specification. If so, then which one ?

Comment: Please check whether port 22 in VM firewall rules is blocked or there are any blockers in org level?